# How to generate unique id in mysql?

Tags: php, mysql

I would like to know how to generate a unique id for every visitor in mysql. I would also like to know how I can place it at the end of a url, like so: http://example.com/?id=12345

Answer (score 6):

You can insert the new user as a row in a table which has an **auto-increment primary key** column and then use php function [`mysql_insert_id()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-insert-id.php). That will give you the last inserted id, which is unique.

As of putting it as the end of the URL, you can just add it (simple string concatenate) to the `href=""` of the links, but that's probably a bad design, so I strongly recommend not to recognize users by some parameter they're passing in GET. You should never need it. Use sessions, cookies, etc...

Comment: +1 For noting the bad practice on the adding the id to the url.  @user.... you should look into sessions/session management on whatever server side framework/code you're using.

Comment: can you show this in a script?

Comment: I had a good answer to share, and I did. For homework, I mean everything *made-by-others-and-ready-to-get-pasted-in-my-own-work-but-I-don't-want-to-figure-out-how-the-hell-it's-done*. I gave you all the indications, you can work it out or pay someone (even me) $40 bucks/hour to write some code. But never mind, some other user will reply and do some free work for you asking. Cheers.

Comment: What if he want's a short url to a specific user profile? How do you solve that without have some variable in the url?

Comment: Look a the words 'probably' and 'recognize users'. I cannot read one's mind, so I just gave a good advice basing on an intuition, but I can be easily contradicted. It's like "if you're thinking about doing that, then don't do it. If you are not, then ignore my advice."

Answer (score 2):

I really must second what Giacomo said about NOT using an id that is shown to the world, but if you want home work try http://www.tizag.com/phpT/phpsessions.php for basic sessions info. But if you are storing personal info and heaven forbid credit card info or the like you must be careful with how you use sessions, Google "session security hole" and you will get About 263,000 results. In short use session but don't use it if your not going to do it right.

Comment: Doh.. that tutorial is everlasting. +1

Answer (score 1):

For retrieving id from the url

```
    $userID = $_GET['id'];
```

Comment: downvote without a comment is very mature. Perhaps you can tell us how to retrieve the variable from the url without using GET?

Comment: Sorry. Here you are: the answer is incomplete, since it only covers part of the question, and while covering that part is not exact, because he asked how to "place it at the end of the url", which is nonsense but that's not "grab it from the url". Sorry again.

Answer (score 0):

Use PHP's built-in [`uniqid`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.uniqid.php) function