# How to make an auto-adding MySQL table with unique id increment?

Tags: mysql, database, increment

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to generate unique id in mysql?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5792476/how-to-generate-unique-id-in-mysql)

I'm wondering how to make a mysql table which automatically adds every unique visitor to the table and gives them a unique id, which is incremented by 1. For example if a visitor goes to my site, I want mysql to store them in a table and to give them a unique id.

**Visitor:** John

**ID:** 12345

Does anyone know how this can be done?

Answer (score 1):

For unique ids you have sequence in MySql. But for other information and insertion of that information in mysql you have to write a program. It can not be done automatically. At least not the way you are willing to do.

Comment: i have seen a website which does this, so i know that its possible.

Comment: @user725446: that website should run some script on page load or may be anywhere else but without running a script this is not possible.[AFAIK]

Comment: do you mean a script which adds the user to the table? If so, do you know how that script would look like?

Comment: I guess a stored procedure could make it LOOK like that, by filtering dupe inserts out.  But better just code that mechanism, it won't be any slower and it will be much easier to maintain.