# How to display a unique id with $_GET?

Tags: php, get

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to generate unique id in mysql?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5792476/how-to-generate-unique-id-in-mysql)

I have a `uniqid()` php script on my site which generates a unique id for every unique visitor. I would like to give each user a unique link which is displayed in a an input form, in the form of `http://website.com/?id=12345` . Does anyone know how to do this?

I saw a different site accomplish this, so I know it's possible. I also know that I have to use the `$_GET` function since there is a `?` after the url. Help.

Comment: what you mean for "unique link which is displayed in an input form"

Comment: it is displayed in a form. for example, on stackoverflow the search bar displays the text "search".

Comment: Do you want to submit the unique id along with a form? Or do you just want the unique id to be visible in the address bar to the user at all time (http://website.com/?id=12345)?

Comment: i just want the unique id to be visible.

Comment: Certainly my fault but I still don't understand what you mean for "unique link which is displayed in an input form" and I suspect there's a bad design behind this. However with PHP you can simply concatenate strings, so put "http://www.whatever.com/?id=".$someid whenever you like and you're done. But try to do sensible things.

Comment: Oh god, how many questions can you possibly ask about the same thing?

Comment: It's the second time he makes this question and I still don't see it clear when it comes to "display this unique link" who-knows-where... It's the second time I say "just concatenate that shit as a string" but I probably don't understand the question. Muh. My fault. If someone can decode this question I'm glad to answer

Answer (score 3):

```
<form action="http://website.com/" method="get">
 <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?=uniqid()?>" />
 <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

This should do the trick...

---

Then on the page you submit to...

```
<?php
 echo $_GET['id'];
?>
```

Comment: Append ?id=<?=uniqid()?> to the action url instead, if the form method is post.

Comment: @thomas, it's better not to rely on short tags being enabled; use `?id=<?php echo uniqid() ?>` instead.